# mysql select all records after certain trigger value in seperate field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, record

I need to select all records after a specific trigger "bar"

```
Item    Trigger  Time
M1      foo      11:11
M1      foo      11:12
M1      bar      11:13
M1      foo      11:14
M1      bar      11:15
M2      foo      11:11
```

I need to return everything for M1 after and including 11:13

```
M1        11:13
M1        11:14
M1        11:15
```

so in pseudo code it would be something like 
select all records like M1 after initial bar?

Comment: You should edit your answer to show what you have tried and how the results vary from what you expect, did you get an error or is the data returned different from what you expected?

Comment: Hint: Main select = select all rows for M1 with time >= result of subselect. The subselect will select the first bar for M1. Hint2 "first" = MIN(Time).

Comment: thanks @Turophile, the sub-query did the trick:
`select Item from Table where Item = 'M1' and Time =>(select min(Time) from Table where trigger = bar)`